# JQuery Filter Select Options by Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is it possible to use jquery to filter select options to only show options with a certain value?
Say I had this:

```
var testArray = ["foo", "bar"];

<select id="dropdown">
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>baz</option>
    <option>foo</option>
</select>
```

After my script executes, I'd like to be left with the following:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>foo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all elements which are not in your array using `.not()` and `$.inArray()`, and then remove them using `.remove()`.

See example below:

```js
var testArray = ["foo", "bar"];
$("#dropdown option").not(function() {
  return $.inArray($(this).val(), testArray) > -1;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>baz</option>
  <option>foo</option>
</select>
```